# Does the STL specify the header guards for its headers?

Tags: c++, stl, include-guards

I want to supply some inline convenience functions using `std::string` in my header alongside with the library functions which use `const char *`, but I do not want to include `<string>`. I want to check with `#ifdef` if `<string>` is included and provide the convenience functions if this is the case.

Question: Are the names of header guards in STL headers the same for all STL implementations? In Visual Studio 2010, the header guard of `<string>` is `_STRING_`.

Comment: Generally having includes have different effects based on order will confuse people.

Comment: In C++17 you could use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?search=string_view). It is much lighter to include than `std::string` and provides a read-only view into either a `std::string` or a `const char*`. Of course this only works if you don't have to mutate the string.

Comment: The standard requires **only** that the headers work correctly if included multiple times. Header guards are the most common mechanism, but they are not required.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a BAD IDEA™.

Generally, you cannot and shouldn't rely on an implementation detail of a compiler / library<sup>1</sup>. On top on that, as stated by [Fire Lancer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6266/fire-lancer) in the comments, *"having includes have different effects based on order will confuse people"* and adds to the wtf/line of your library.

What you could (should?) do is document a macro for the user to define in order to enable your `std::string` functions:

```
#ifdef MY_LIBRARY_ENABLE_STRING_FUNCTIONS
void print(std::string message);
#endif // MY_LIBRARY_ENABLE_STRING_FUNCTIONS
```

If the user wants them, they'll have to:

```
#define MY_LIBRARY_ENABLE_STRING_FUNCTIONS
#include <my_library>
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> C++17 has the [`__has_include(<filename>)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) macro (credit to [acraig5075](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332041/acraig5075) for learning this to me) which doesn't help as it returns whether an include is available and not if it has been included.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestions. Despite I changed my mind about doing what I intended, I am still curous if the header guard names in STL are standardized. Do you have any information on this?

Comment: @Fabian No, they are not. They could use `#pragma once` or any builtin compiler magic if their developer wanted. They could even disobey the One Definition Rule, after all don't forget that the Standard Library isn't properly written in C++ and the C++ Standard doesn't _fully_ apply to it.

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way to check would probably be using [sfinae](/questions/tagged/sfinae) technique.

That being said, **DON'T DO THIS**, everything screams anti-pattern when you want to differentiate on whether a header has been included or not, or the order of includes.

Comment: It’s very hard to SFINAE on the absence of a declaration entirely; you can’t recover from non-dependent lookup failure.